# .NET AddIn Framework, ignore folder (.svn)

Tags: .net, add-in, maf

Is it possible to make the AddInStore of the AddIn Framework (MAF) to ignore a certain directory?

In my case the addin store is versioned by subversion but when the pipeline is rebuild I get the error that the ".svn" folder in AddIns does not contain a valid addin:

> Could not find a valid add-in in the directory [..]\AddIns\.svn.

Comment: Note: I know I could simply ignore the warnings which are returned by AddInStore.Rebuild but than I would ignore all or would try to filter those warnings which contain the string ".svn" - this does not seem best practice to me.

Comment: Please avoid greetings, taglines and etc. It draw the attention of the reader off the question and shorten the relevant data in the tooltip preview. You are more likely to receive answers that way. [Read more about the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @HuBeZa: Just thought it would look kind of inpolite but I see the subject (under your link). Will keep in mind in the future.

Comment: I don't make the rules, the community make the rules :) BTW: almost everything goes in comments, except spam, profanity, hate speach etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now doing it this way:

```
List<String> warnings = new List<String>(AddInStore.Rebuild(appPath));

// remove warnings about .svn directories
for (int i = warnings.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (warnings[i].Contains(".svn")) warnings.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just want to add I now surround the for-loop with conditional compiling "#if DEBUG" so this code will not go into releases.